# Marginal distribution of 4x4 Wishart matrix elements

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance, marginal-distribution

Suppose we have the variance matrix, which is Wishart distributed:

$\begin{pmatrix}
s_1 & c_{12} & c_{13} & c_{14}\\
c_{21} & s_2 & c_{23} & c_{24}\\
c_{31} & c_{32} & s_3 & c_{34}\\
c_{41} & c_{42} & c_{43} & s_4
\end{pmatrix}$

What I am trying to define is the marginal distribution of its right upper part:
$\begin{pmatrix}
c_{13} & c_{14}\\
c_{23} & c_{24}\\
\end{pmatrix}$

I know that it is possible to find the marginal distribution of off-diagonal elements of 2x2 Wishart matrix by using variance-gamma distribution:

$f_{c_{ij}} = \dfrac{|c_{ij}|^\tfrac{n-1}{2}}{\Gamma(\dfrac{n}{2}) \sqrt{2^{n-1} \pi (1-\rho^2) (\sigma_i \sigma_j)^{n+1}}} K_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}} (\dfrac{|c_{ij}|}{\sigma_i \sigma_j (1-\rho^2)}) \text{exp} (\dfrac{\rho c_{ij}} {\sigma_i \sigma_j (1-rho^2)})$,

where $K$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $c_{ij}$ - the off-diagonal element, $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ - diagonal elements.

Is it possible to somehow modify this definition for 4x4 case? Or is it valid to apply it directly to the case of 2x2 submatrix I am trying to consider?